# Qt cannot find his own headers when i try to include header to create unit test for Google test

Tags: qt, unit-testing, googletest

I want to add unit test for my game using google test tool but when i want to include header for tested class Qt throw error in included header that he miss Qt lib.

> room.h:6: error: QtGui: No such file or directory

This error wasnt occured before.

Is this because i have something wrong with project config?

Comment: Yes, your project configuration seems to be incorrect, particularly part where it defines include directories paths.

Comment: did you add `QT += core gui` to your pro file ?

Comment: This is my unit test project *pro file 

include(gtest_dependency.pri)

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += thread
CONFIG -= qt

HEADERS +=     tst_testy.h \
    mock_room.h \
    mock_character.h

SOURCES +=     main.cpp \
    mock_room.cpp

Comment: Simon - I added this before and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `CONFIG -= qt` means you do not use Qt for your project, so its normal it does not find Qt headers.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. Now it works perfectly. It was default setting so i wasn't check that.